# LFS-6.25. Attr-2.4.48 fails at "make check"

Tags: linux, fedora, lfs

I'm having an issue with Chapter 6.25 version 8.3. I followed the instructions but when I came to the `make check` part it showed me the output:

```
(lfs chroot) root:/sources/attr-2.4.48# make check
Making check in po
make[1]: Entering directory '/sources/attr-2.4.48/po'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'check'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/sources/attr-2.4.48/po'
make[1]: Entering directory '/sources/attr-2.4.48'
make  check-TESTS
make[2]: Entering directory '/sources/attr-2.4.48'
make[3]: Entering directory '/sources/attr-2.4.48'
PASS: test/attr.test
FAIL: test/root/getfattr.test
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for attr 2.4.48
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 2
# PASS:  1
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  1
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
See ./test-suite.log
Please report to acl-devel@nongnu.org
============================================================================
```

As you can see that failed `getfattr.test` but I don't know why it failed.

I need to understand why I came to this solution.

EDIT:

Adding the `./test-suite.log` [file](https://pastebin.com/raw/zjNXW1L4).

Comment: I see this is tagged "Fedora", so I assume you used Fedora as your host OS? Are you by any chance using ext4? If so, then I too have the same issue (albeit with LFS version 8.4), and it could be something to do with Fedora's ext4 formatting tools.